# How to set default file for "directory" route

Tags: reactor-netty

I can create `.directory()` route for http server, for example, on `/` path, but it only provide files by their direct links, like `/index.html`. How can i make it redirect to `/index.html` from `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments, i found solution that did work for me.

```
routes.file("/", destinationDir + File.separator + "index.html");
routes.directory("/", Paths.get(destinationDir);
```

This works due to in case of file, router needs exactly matching path, and in case of directory prefix comparsion executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess file for same.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```